# Facebook message API privacy settings, is the message shown in the timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

Currently I'm working on a simple Facebook App which posts message to boards of different users. I got this to work, but we don't want to show this message in the timeline. Of course the best solution for this is sending a private message, but for my understanding the API is currently not able to do that.

So my question is: following this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ API description should I use the NO_FRIEND flag in the privacy setting to prevent it for showing in the timeline? Or ar there other flags that can do that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the part I think you didn't see in the API documentation:

> Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or
>   specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted
>   Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page,
>   event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on
>   Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the
>   target's Wall.

So, the privacy only deals with posts to the user's wall.

Comment: Okay, so that implies that it appears in the timeline. That's too bad for us, I'll give it a try weather or not it appears in the timeline.

Comment: Correct, this is a limitation that Facebook imposed on the API to prevent abuse.